Internal VLANs in Hetzner with Proxmox
In a Hetzner Dedicated Host with Proxmox and OpnSense, I want to setup 2 VLANs at root-level, having only 1 Public IP and without using any VSwitch or extra IPs, if possible.
The idea of having 2 VLANs is to have unsafe content on one VLAN that doesn't affect the work VLAN.
My current configuration which currently works is below.
It routes through OpnSense which has WAN set to vmbr0.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr99
iface vmbr99 inet static
        address 10.1.1.0/24
        gateway 10.1.1.200 #OpnSense IP
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

The vmbr99 bridge for 10.1.1.0 should ideally upstream to VLAN1. A second subnet 10.1.2.0 should upstream to VLAN2.
The VLAN boundary should end within these 2 VLANs and child subnets.
When a packet is forwarded to eno1 interface, it's VLAN tag should be removed. This is to avoid requiring a VSwitch at Hetzner Host level.
Actually Hetzner should be totally unaware of the existence of these 2 VLANs.
I've already tried https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#sysadmin_network_routed, where I found below snippet.
But it doesn't seem to work, there is no network connectivity and I cannot ping Hetzner's IP.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno1.5 inet manual

auto vmbr0v5
iface vmbr0v5 inet static
        address  10.10.10.2/24
        gateway  10.10.10.1
        bridge-ports eno1.5
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

Some help would be very helpful at this point as I don't know what else to try.
Thank you!

Actually Hetzner should be totally unaware of the existence of these 2 VLANs. only 1 Public IP Your attempt does not make any sense. Why would you be messing with the WAN bridge when you are really trying to have one more LAN? Theoretically you don't even need "VLAN", instead you should just create another LAN bridge and add one more LAN interface to the OPNsense VM. If you insists on doing it the VLAN way, what you need isn't dot1q interfaces in proxmox, but enabling VLAN filtering in the LAN bridge (which isn't really scalable, since "bridge ports" of the VM would "come and go".).

The only maybe-sensical VLAN approach (instead of sinple multi-LAN) I could think of is, you create a "VLAN bridge" which connects the two LAN bridges and the OPNsense VM, then enable VLAN filtering in the VLAN bridge, then you add dot1q interfaces in the OPNsense VM (in other words, "router on a stick").

Actually I might be wrong about one thing -- proxmox might allow you to set VLAN ID(s) for the "bridge ports" (i.e. the taps) in the VM's NIC setting, so you may be fine with one LAN bridge with VLAN filtering enabled. Still you would either have two LAN interfaces for the OPNsense VM, or you do router on a stick by adding dot1q interfaces in it.

Why? What's the point in multiple VLANs on a single hypervisor?

I want to have unsafe content in the other VLAN without affecting the main (work) VLAN.

VLAN is ethernet thing, really related to presenting a physical cable as several virtual cables.
In case where all your ethernet interfaces are virtual anyway, for instance, where there is just a single hypervisor, there is no point in denoting things as "VLANs". You can just create as many virtual ethernet networks as you want, without complicating things. Pretend a concept of "VLANs" doesn't exists. Create several purely virtual bridges without connecting them to a physical NIC, that's your "VLANs".

But isn't it easier to configure VLANs since they already have the tag which dissalows packages to accidentally go to other VLAN? With normal LANS you need to configure firewall rules

@monikan VLAN isn't magic. What it really does in reality is just allow you to have less pieces of hardware (which is why it pretty much makes no sense when you are working in a virtual environment). When you connect two VLANs to a router, once the scope is L3 forwarding, they have no difference from LANs. In other words, the tagging stuff is nothing but something the router needs to "resolve" at L2. As I written in my answer, once the "resolution" is done, whether they can communicate with each other through the router still depends on the L3 firewall, just like when you have two LANs.

@monikan Might be worth mentioning that, if you take a good look at my answer, you'll notice that only the first step of configuration in OPNsense is VLAN specific. It is also the only step you don't need if you have two LAN NICs (with VLAN ID set) for the OPNsense VM. I hope that could help you see how VLAN is really just a way to make one bridge serves as multiple (and tags that would retain outside the bridge is just a way to make one "port pair" / link serves as multiple, and dot1q interface is what used to "resolve" / "differentiate" traffics arriving at the host end).

While I doubt that there is a good reason not to have an extra LAN bridge (in addition to vmbr99) instead, I have come up with an answer do it in the VLAN (router on a stick) approach, just because that's what you asked about.
First of all, you make your LAN bridge "VLAN aware" (i.e. enable VLAN filtering):

You can optionally create a 802.1Q (dot1q) interface on the LAN bridge interface if you want to be able to reach the VMs in VLAN 2 from the proxmox host (like ssh or whatever):

The corresponding sections of /etc/network/interface would look like this:
auto opnlan
iface opnlan inet static
        address 10.0.202.2/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 2-4094

auto opnlan.2
iface opnlan.2 inet static
        address 10.0.222.2/24

(Since apparently in your case you need the traffics from the proxmox host to go through OPNsense as well, you can add a gateway to either the LAN bridge section or its dot1q interface. My point is, there's probably no reason you would need to have one in both sections.)
Then you can set the VLAN ID for each VM in its NIC setting. You should leave the field blank for the OPNsense VM, so that proxmox will make its bridge port a "trunk port". (It seems that there is no "proxmox-way" to assign just a couple VLAN to a VM / its bridge port. What proxmox does is that it assigns VLAN 1-4094 to it when you leave the field blank Nevertheless, that's fine for the setup in concern. It's just that you probably really can't have something like two OPNsense VMs sharing a LAN bridge and have proxmox assign VLAN 1 and 2 to one of them and VLAN 3 and 4 to the other.)

Then you need to create a dot1q interface in your OPNsense VM on its LAN interface:

"Assign" it:

And configure it:

(Make sure you scroll down and fill in the IP address field, save and apply changes.)
As suggested, you probably want to configure the DHCP server for the new VLAN:

And you will also need to allow traffics from it:

Note that by default OPNsense would probably allow routing between the VLANs. You'll need to configure the firewall rules properly if you to forbid communication between them. If you don't know how to do it, that's really another question.
P.S. "Router on a stick" is not the only approach you can take even when you want to share one LAN bridge and leverage VLAN. You can add an extra NIC to the VM instead. In that case you do not need to create dot1q interface in the VM. Instead, you set corresponding VLAN ID in setting of the two LAN NICs. But again, why not two LAN bridges then?

Could you please add the whole interfaces file? I don't know how to connect the existing bridges to the VLANs you created

@monikan You don't even need to. The answer is written for the original interface file you have. You had only two bridges, if you can't even tell which bridge you should "work on" even with my answer and comments, then probably you should just keep things simple and clean, especially when neither multiple LANs nor VLANs means "security automatic". Also the answer is really more about giving you and the others an overview of the "structure" of a VLAN setup, in other words it's essentially for "educational" purpose, not really for you to copy and paste and use.
